# Multiple logical operators in if..else staterment in php

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

firstname and lastname are being submitted from a HTML form.

In PHP i want to check that both of them must be atleast 3 characters long and maximum upto 18 characters.
How can i check it in an `if else` statement

Example code is below

```
$f = $_POST['firstname'];
$l = $_POST['lastname'];
if((strlen($f) < 3 || strlen($f) > 16) && (strlen($l) < 3 || strlen($l) > 16))
{
    echo "Firstname and lastname must be between 3 and 16 characters";
    exit();
}
```

It is not working what i have done wrong.....

Thanks for help and I hope you understand my problem

Comment: 18 or 16? HAve to be at least 3 and at top 18 included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if((strlen($f) < 3 || strlen($f) > 16) || (strlen($l) < 3 || strlen($l) > 16))
```

Replace `&&` in the middle by `||`

What you did only throws the error when both aren't valid.
You want to throw it when one of them is.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
if((strlen($f) <= 3 && strlen($f) >= 18 ) && (strlen($l) <= 3 && strlen($l) >= 18 ))
{
echo "Firstname and lastname must be between 3 and 16 characters";
}
else
{
//query here..
}
```